# Is there a known compatibility problem between Cordova and Galaxy?

Tags: android, cordova, samsung-mobile

I am testing a Cordova app on Amazon Device Farm. It runs smoothly on all devices except Samsung (all models and API's), on which some of the graphics are ill displayed (just HTML and CSS; the Canvas parts actually display well. No libraries are used). Otherwise the app works as expected. It also passes all default automated tests on AWS Device Farm.

I am using:

- cordova 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

Installed platforms:

- android 8.1.0

cordova plugin ls:

- cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
- cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
- cordova-plugin-media 5.0.3 "Media"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"

Here's an example of all the errors of a device log (this one is from Samsung Galaxy A40):
[image]

I don't find a clue here as to what might cause the problem, but this is my first app so I might be missing something obvious here.

Reported issues of Cordova - Galaxy pairing (such as this: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/879) also did not help me find a solution.

I wonder if anyone else had encountered such a problem and what might be a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to root cause this?

Comment: @NikofTime What exactly do you mean?